# How to create PopupWindow on startup in android?

Tags: android, android-dialog

It is possible using **Dialog** class but I do not want it that way. Instead I want it to be done by using **PopupWindow** class which gets popped up on startup and display some message on the popup. I am helpless, just can not getting this after spending many days behind it. Hope I get it here. Please and Thanks. Also look at below snippet if you didn't get what I want..

```
public class PopupActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(ll);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final PopupWindow pw;
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Hello");
        pw = new PopupWindow(button, 245, 284, true);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) {  
                pw.dismiss();            
            }  
        });

        pw.showAsDropDown(ll, 10, -50);
    }
}
```

Above code gives me FORCE CLOSE :/ Help guys..

Comment: Post the stack trace, and tell us what line the error is at. We can then tell you what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how you may show a popup window.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutTemp">

</LinearLayout>
```

**popup_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Test Pop-Up" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            showPopup();
        }
    }, 100);
}


public void showPopup(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null, false), 100, 100, true);
    pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.layoutTemp), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

The idea is that your popup will be displayed once your activity is loaded, otherwise it will produce exception *Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?*. Unless you show popup on a button click, that is the reason I'm showing it after a delay of 100 milliseconds (which is almost unnoticeable).

Comment: yes, its correct. That's why i'm loading it after 100 milliseconds

Comment: You shouldn't do this. What if for some reason creation takes more than 100ms?

Comment: then either increase the time or better doing it in onResume